# python:termcolorを使って色を変えようとすると?[32mtest?[0mと表記されてしまう。

Tags: python, visual-studio

VS codeを使いPythonを勉強している初学者です。
termcolorで色を変えようとしたところ、`?[32mtest?[0m` と表記されてしまいます。
どなたかご教授頂けると幸いです。

```
from termcolor import colored

print('test')
print(colored('test', 'green'))
```

Answer (score 2):

`?[0m` はおそらく `ESC[0m` のことで、これは `vt100` 端末エスケープシーケンスというものです。むかし昔によく使われていた「端末」画面上で色を変える手続きの１つなのですが、残念ながら Windows のコンソールはこの `vt100` エスケープシーケンスに対応していません。そのため Windows のコンソール上は色が変わらずに文字化けして見えます。要するに今あなたのところの設定は Linux 端末 (`vt100`) 用になっていて Windows コンソール用の設定ではないのです。

Windows コンソール上で色をつけるには `colorama` をつかうとよいです。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21858567/

Comment: see also; https://teratail.com/questions/260791

Comment: ありがとうございます。内容を見て理解するとが出来ました。今後ともよろしくお願いいたします。